# Does LruCache in android give you a significant performance difference against sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, caching

I have an application that uses a sqlite database to present data about movies to the user. Each movie record in the database contains basically strings and integers.

Every time that the activity is re-created, the database is queried for the necessary "movies".

My question is the following:

If I were to create a LruCache when the app is launched to avoid querying the database each time, would there be a performance improvement? Would it be "significant"?

Although LruCache can cache anything, I thought that it would be helpful mainly for bitmap caching, as bitmaps are quite memory intensive. Is there any other situations in which it can provide a significant performance improvement?

Sorry for the ignorance, but I would really like to know well what this tool is for.

Thanks!

Comment: depends on the complexity of your query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LRUCaches are really only useful when you need to only cache a certain number of things-  for example with bitmaps you frequently create a cache of a fixed size so you only cache say 100MB of images, and everything else fails.  THis allows you to avoid OOM issues (please note LRUCache isn't magical, you still have to code your app to use it correctly to get this advantage).  The cost of it is that you'll preallocate most/all of that cache before its needed.

If you have something where the total memory used isn't 10s-100s of MB, you're better off just using a Map instead.  Its quicker and easier.

As for LRUCache or Map vs Sqlite-  yes, it would be quicker.  If you have an anti-pattern like querying the database for every getView in a list, you should avoid that.  But if you're querying for eveything up front and then saving it elsewhere in the application, repeating the query again for major things like a new activity/fragment is unlikely to be high cost.  Also remember that an LRUCache is not persistent-  it will need to be recreated from scratch the next time your app is launched.  If you need to track changes or are trying to minimize server queries a local db is probably better.

Comment: Great answer, really instructive. Just one more thing if you don't mind: this application has a search feature, where the user inserts a query and I make an API call to check how many movies match the query (and download them as json). In this concrete case, would a cache be worth it? If so, what kind of cache. Thank you.

Comment: Caches don't really help with non key-value queries.  If you want to search for all movie's who's title starts with A, the cache wouldn't be able to answer it.  You'd need to go linearly over all the queries in the cache, which may actually be slower than a db.  (There are techniques you could use to improve it, but taken to the extreme you'd basically be writing a db inside of your app).  If you need relational queries, you're best off just using a db.